# How to create a return statement in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have following sql on SQL server

```
declare @groupName varchar(50)

select   @groupName=groupIdentifier from tab1 where col3 ='ABC'

if @groupName is not NULL
    select @groupName
    return

select   @groupName=col2 from tab2 where col1= 'BCD'
if @groupName is not NULL
    select @groupName
    return
```

I translated into RedShift as follows:

```
 create temp table t1
(groupName)
---- Statement 1 -----
insert into t1 select groupIdentifier from tab1 where col3 ='ABC'
---- Statement 2 -----
insert into t1 select col2 from tab2 where  col1= 'BCD' and (select count(1) from t1)=0
select * from t1
```

As there is no return statement in RedShift , Statement 2 always gets executed even when Statement 1 was able to fetch row. As second statement is expensive, how do I efficiently prevent it from being executed if Statement 1 is successful.

Comment: pleasr remove postgresql tag - its not the same as redshift

Comment: you need to control this using a scripting language outside of redshift.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot recreate this logic using only SQL statements on Redshift. Redshift SQL syntax does not contain control-of-flow commands like `IF` and `RETURN`.

Typically, you will need some kind of external program or script to manage the control-of-flow logic to work out which SQL statements to execute and what result to return.